The probability that j distinct elements of a group compose to identity? The probability if each element is taken to the j-th power?
I have been playing with a problem for a while, there seems to be both patterns, and also a lack of an obvious solution. For each finite group $G$ of order $n$, we will define an $n \times n$ matrix. Let's start with abelian groups, and we will work with $C_{p^n}$ represented by numbers modulo $p$: $\{0, 1, \ldots, p\}$.
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. Consider the sum of an unordered $j$-tuples $(g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_j)$ of distinct elements from $G$, with $j \leq n$. How often is it equal to identity? We can use unordered pairs, since $G$ is abelian for now.
For example, for $C_2$, there is:

1-tuple: $(\operatorname{id})$
2-tuple: none

for $C_3$, there is:

1-tuple: $(\operatorname{id})$
2-tuple $(1,2)$
3-tuple $(0,1,2)$

for $C_4$, there is:

1-tuple: $(\operatorname{id})$
2-tuple: $(1,3)$
3-tuple: $(0,1,3)$
4-tuple: none

Next, for $i \leq n$, define the probability matrix of a group as:
$$
P_{(i,j)}(G) = \Pr \left( \sum_{k=1}^j i \cdot g_k = 0 \right)
$$
We can define these values for any group $(G,+)$ with $i, j \leq n$.
To clarify by probability in this case I mean the proportion of $j$-tuples: For the finite abelian case, we take distinct j-tuples. For a group of order $n$, there are $\binom{n}{j}$ such tuples. We are checking what proportion of those j-tuples have elements that compose to identity. For the $i$-th row, we transform the $j$-tuple to $(g_1, \dots , g_j)$ by composing each element to itself $i$ times to get $(i \cdot g_1, \dots , i \cdot g_j)$, then we compose these elements together to see if we get $id$.
Here are some example matrices:
\begin{align}
P_{i,j}(C_2) & = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
P_{i,j}(C_3) & = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
P_{i,j}(C_4) & = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
P_{i,j}(C_2 \times C_2) &= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Some observations:

The pattern $C_p$, $p$ an odd prime is clear, it's $\frac{1}{p}$ everywhere, except the last row / column whose values are $1$.

The values on row and column numbers which are co-prime to the group order also seem to be $1/n$


Question(s)

Has this problem been studied?
Can we get a full characterisation for finite abelian groups?
Is the probability matrix unique for finite groups (including non-abelian ones)?
Is it unique in general for a group?
Can it be reconstructed from the lattice of subgroups?
For a non-finite group with a finite generating set, can we create a similar probability matrix on the generating set? Would it be well-defined regardless of the choice of generating set?


I don’t understand the setup. You’re considering a probability, but what’s random there? What measure do you put on the $g_k$?

I don't understand the definition of the probability matrix, and the examples don't really help. For example, afaict the probability that $x + y = 0$ given that $x \neq y$ should be $\frac{1}{6}$ in $C_4$, since $1 + 3 = 0$ but $0$ and $2$ are involutive so distinct pairs containing any one of these won't satisfy $x + y = 0$. But I don't see $\frac{1}{6}$ anywhere in the matrix of $C_4$. Could you provide a textual description of what the $i,j$ coefficient of the probability matrix should be?

@CorentinB, for the finite abelian case, we take distinct j-tuples. For a group of order $n$, there are $\binom{n}{j}$ such tuples. We are checking what proportion of those j-tuples compose to identity.
So, I think in the finite case at least it's pretty simple. I wouldn't know how to extend it naturally to non-finite groups. Perhaps, one could study it on finitely generated groups on the generating set. I wonder if the probability matrix for a group is always the same then regardless of choice of the generating set.

@Z.A.K. you are correct, I edited it. The 1st row, $j$-th column contains the probability that a distinct j-tuple composes to $id$. So, as you pointed out $P_{(1,2)}(C_4) = \frac{1}{6}$. For the $i$-th row, we first transform the distinct $j$-tuple to $(i \cdot g_1, \dots , i \cdot g_j)$ and then see if it composes to $id$. I hope that's clearer. If you have a suggestion, I can add it to the post to make it more clear.
